# CAAnimation do not execute without fromValue?

Tags: ios, caanimation

This is the sample code:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(textField)
    let anime = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "shadowOffset")
    anime.toValue = NSValue(CGSize: CGSizeMake(0, 10))
    anime.duration = 0.3

    textField.layer.addAnimation(anime, forKey: "to")
    textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 10)
}
```

I think this code works fine before. The switch between `PresentationLayer` and `modalLayer` is perfect.

However, here `shadowOffset` is set to `CGSizeMake(0, 10)` immediately.

---

When i give the animation a `fromValue`

```
anime.fromValue = NSValue(CGSize: CGSizeMake(0, 0))
```

The animation works.

The document mentioned the former situation:

> toValue is non-nil. Interpolates between the current value of keyPath in the target layer’s presentation layer and toValue.

So why i cannot get the animation accurate without setting the `fromValue` now?

*ps: i am using XCode6.3*

Answer (score 0):

You need a fromValue because the animation doesn't know what it should animate from. Setting the toValue and animating jumps the content because without a start value, it doesn't know how to interpolate the values.

You can set the fromValue to the current value, like `anime.fromValue = textField.layer.shadowOffset`.